# ffmpeg returned non-zero exit status. Check stdout Coldfusion

Tags: video, ffmpeg, coldfusion

I have an coldfusion application. I am converting recorded video from mobile through ffmpeg and coldfusion. Here is the ffmpeg command which i am running.

ffmpegPath -i "inputfile" -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac "OutputFile"

Output file type is mp4. I want to convert my all videos to mp4 with h.264 and ACC sound. So that it will work on all platforms.

I am getting the following error:

```
java.io.IOException: ffmpeg returned non-zero exit status. Check stdout.
```

Here is the CF code that i am running.

```
<cfset resultLog        = "path\to\directory\testOuput_result.log">
<cfset errorLog         = "path\to\directory\testOuput_error.log">
<cfset results  = structNew()> 
        <cfscript>
            try {  
                runtime = createObject("java", "java.lang.Runtime").getRuntime();
                command = 'ffmpegPath -i "inputfile" -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac "OutputFile"';
                process = runtime.exec(#command#);
                results.errorLogSuccess = processStream(process.getErrorStream(), errorLog);  
                results.resultLogSuccess = processStream(process.getInputStream(), resultLog);  
                results.exitCode = process.waitFor();  
            }  
            catch(exception e) {  
                results.status = e;      
            }  
        </cfscript>
<cffunction name="processStream" access="public" output="false" returntype="boolean" hint="Returns true if stream was successfully processed">  
    <cfargument name="in" type="any" required="true" hint="java.io.InputStream object">  
    <cfargument name="logPath" type="string" required="false" default="" hint="Full path to LogFile">  
    <cfset var out = "">  
    <cfset var writer = "">  
    <cfset var reader = "">  
    <cfset var buffered = "">  
    <cfset var line = "">  
    <cfset var sendToFile = false>  
    <cfset var errorFound = false>  

    <cfscript>  
        if ( len(trim(arguments.logPath)) ) {  
            out = createObject("java", "java.io.FileOutputStream").init(arguments.logPath);  
            writer = createObject("java", "java.io.PrintWriter").init(out);  
            sendToFile = true;  
        }  

        reader = createObject("java", "java.io.InputStreamReader").init(arguments.in);  
        buffered = createObject("java", "java.io.BufferedReader").init(reader);  
        line = buffered.readLine();  
        while ( IsDefined("line") ) {  
            if (sendToFile) {  
                writer.println(line);  
            }  
            line = buffered.readLine();  
        }      
           if (sendToFile) {  
           errorFound = writer.checkError();  
           writer.flush();  
           writer.close();  
        }  
    </cfscript>  
    <!--- return true if no errors found. --->  
    <cfreturn (NOT errorFound)>  
</cffunction>
```

I have also used different ffmpeg.exe but got same error. I have also used [ffmpeg-cli-wrapper](https://github.com/bramp/ffmpeg-cli-wrapper) java wrapper in coldfusion. Still i got the same error. Can any one help me to sort out this issue.

Comment: _Check stdout_ - so what does the stdout say?  Did you see these similar questions?  [reference 1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25067927/1636917) - [reference 2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27920837/1636917) - [reference 3](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10066322/1636917)

Comment: @Miguel-F. Thanks for your response. Yes i see them. I am able to resolve it. I was not passing absolute path of input file to ffmpeg that was causing the issue.

Comment: Ok great. Glad you resolved it. Please add an answer to this question with the details so that others will see what the solution was.

Comment: @Miguel-F. ok. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to resolve this issue. The problem is in inputfile path. I have fixed this by passing absolute path of inputfile to ffmpeg

Comment: Nothing to do with the error, but are you sure you actually need Runtime.exec()? In older versions, you can invoke ffmpeg with `<cfexecute>` using `/c` and `2>&1`. Did you try that?

Comment: @Leigh. Not tried that. I will give a try to it. Can you please give me some example code for it. Also what is the benefit to use cfexecute  rather than Runtime.exec()?

Comment: The example was too long for comments, so see [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43128069/104223).

Answer (score 2):

Nothing to do with the error, but are you sure you really need `Runtime.exec()`? It is usually overkill. Most applications can be invoked with [`<cfexecute>`](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-d-e/cfexecute.html), which is basically a wrapper of `Runtime.exec()`, which does the same thing, only with less code.

There was [an issue with `cfexecute` and ffmpeg.exe](https://forums.adobe.com/message/1930064#1930064) way back in CF8, caused by the fact that early versions of cfexecute did not capture [StdErr](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#err). However, that was resolved in one of the CF8 updates. Assuming you are using a recent version of CF, it should work right out of the box. Not tested, but something along these lines:

<sub>NB: Note the use of absolute paths for *all* files</sub>

```
<!--- change to the appropriate timeout --->
<cfexecute name="c:\path\to\ffmpeg.exe" 
    arguments=' -i "c:\path\to\in.file" -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac "c:\path\to\out.file"'
    timeout="120" 
    variable="result"
    errorVariable="errorMessage"
    /> 

<!--- Display results --->
<cfoutput>
   result = #result#
   errorVariable = #errorVariable #
</cfoutput>
```

See the [`cfexecute` documentation](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-d-e/cfexecute.html) for more details on arguments and syntax.

Comment: Thanks. I will check the documentation and change it according to it.