# Add watermark in video with Google Cloud function python

Tags: python-3.x, video, ffmpeg, google-cloud-functions

I am adding watermark in uploaded video by http google cloud function but my code is return on ffmpeg non zero. my python code

```
import os
from google.cloud import storage
from subprocess import check_output
from videoprops import get_video_properties


def hello_world(request):

client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.get_bucket('bucket_name')
request_json = request.get_json()
req_data = request.get_json()
name = req_data['file']
videofile_name = req_data['file_name']
os.makedirs('/tmp/'+os.path.dirname(name), exist_ok=True)
file_name = '/tmp/' + name
output_file_name = '/tmp/' + name.split('.')[0] + '_.'+name.split('.')[1]
print(output_file_name)
logo_path = '/temp/watermark.png'
logo_name = 'watermark.png'
print('logo found')

print(file_name)

try:
    os.remove(file_name)
except OSError:
    pass

try:
    os.remove(logo_path)
except OSError:
    pass

print("File has been removed")

# Downloading the video to the cloud functions
blob = bucket.get_blob(name)
blob.download_to_filename(file_name)

blob_logo = bucket.get_blob(logo_name)
blob_logo.download_to_filename(logo_path)

print("Video Downloaded")

props = get_video_properties(file_name)

if os.path.exists(file_name):
    print("NEW MP4 EXISTS")
    #   check_output('ffmpeg  -itsoffset -4  -i '+file_name+' -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 1 -an -f rawvideo -s '+str(props['width'])+'x'+str(props['height'])+' '+thumbnail_file_name, shell=True)
    #   thumbnail_blob = bucket.blob(os.path.dirname(name)+'/thumbnail.jpg')
    #   thumbnail_blob.upload_from_filename(thumbnail_file_name)
    # 19-7-2020
    check_output('ffmpeg  -i '+file_name+' -i '+logo_path +
                 ' -filter_complex overlay=10:10 -codec:a copy -preset ultrafast -async 1 '+output_file_name, shell=True)
    thumbnail_blob = bucket.blob(
        os.path.dirname(name) + '/'+videofile_name)
    thumbnail_blob.upload_from_filename(output_file_name)
    # -------------------------------------
else:
    print("MP4 not created")

print("uploaded")
```

In this code accessing video add watermark also accessing from bucket and applying with ffmpeg and uploading.

**error is :-**

raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'ffmpeg  -i /tmp/Upload/Video/1060/ad69ec74-49db-4fdb-b118-d23b9468a7b8.mp4 -i /temp/watermark.png -filter_complex overlay=10:10 -codec:a copy -preset ultrafast -async 1 /tmp/Upload/Video/1060/ad69ec74-49db-4fdb-b118-d23b9468a7b8_.mp4' returned non-zero exit status 1.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ffmpeg Python Subprocess Error returned non-zero exit status 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25067927/ffmpeg-python-subprocess-error-returned-non-zero-exit-status-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved and using with http request base trigger in google cloud function. May be help to someone in future

```
import os
import os.path
from google.cloud import storage
from subprocess import check_output
from videoprops import get_video_properties


def hello_world(request):
    """Responds to any HTTP request.
    Args:
        request (flask.Request): HTTP request object.
    Returns:
        The response text or any set of values that can be turned into a
        Response object using
        # flask.Flask.make_response>`.
        `make_response <http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/
    """
    client = storage.Client()
    bucket = client.get_bucket('showtalentbucket')
    request_json = request.get_json()
    req_data = request.get_json()
    name = req_data['file']
    videofile_name = req_data['file_name']
    os.makedirs('/tmp/'+os.path.dirname(name), exist_ok=True)
    file_name = '/tmp/' + name
    output_file_name = '/tmp/' + name.split('.')[0] + '_.'+name.split('.')[1]
    mp4_output_file_name = '/tmp/' + \
        name.split('.')[0] + '__.'+name.split('.')[1]
    print(output_file_name)
    logo_path = '/tmp/watermark.png'
    logo_name = 'watermark.png'
    print('logo found')

    print(file_name)

    try:
        os.remove(file_name)
    except OSError:
        pass

    try:
        os.remove(logo_path)
    except OSError:
        pass

    print("File has been removed")

    # Downloading the video to the cloud functions
    blob = bucket.get_blob(name)
    blob.download_to_filename(file_name)

    blob_logo = bucket.get_blob(logo_name)
    blob_logo.download_to_filename(logo_path)

    print("Video Downloaded")

    props = get_video_properties(file_name)

    if os.path.exists(file_name):
        print("NEW MP4 EXISTS")
      
        check_output('ffmpeg  -i '+file_name+' -i '+logo_path +
                     ' -filter_complex overlay=10:10 -codec:a copy -preset ultrafast -async 1 '+output_file_name, shell=True)
        if os.path.splitext(name)[1].lower().startswith('.mov'):
            check_output('ffmpeg  -itsoffset -4  -i '+output_file_name +
                         ' -acodec copy -vcodec copy -f mov '+mp4_output_file_name, shell=True)
            thumbnail_blob = bucket.blob(
                os.path.dirname(name) + '/'+videofile_name)
            thumbnail_blob.upload_from_filename(mp4_output_file_name)
        else:
            thumbnail_blob = bucket.blob(
                os.path.dirname(name) + '/'+videofile_name)
            thumbnail_blob.upload_from_filename(output_file_name)
        # -------------------------------------
    else:
        print("MP4 not created")

    print("uploaded")
```